# Optimization of Sybase 15.5 union query

Tags: t-sql, union, sybase, sap-ase, distinct-values

im having trouble trying to optimize the following query on Sybase 15.5. Does anyone know how could i improve it. Each one of the tables used there have about 30 million rows each. I tried my best to optimize it but still taking lot of time(1.5 hours).

```
create table #tmp1( f_id smallint, a_date smalldatetime )
create table #tmp2( f_id smallint, a_date smalldatetime )


insert #tmp1
select f_id, a_date = max( a_date )
    FROM  audit_table
    WHERE  i_date =  @pIDate
group by f_id

insert #tmp2
select f_id , a_date = max( a_date )
    FROM  n_audit_table
    WHERE  i_date =  @pIDate
group by f_id

    create table #tmp(
    t_account varchar(32) not null,
    t_id varchar(32) not null,
    product varchar(64) null
    )

insert into #tmp
select t_account,t_id, product
    FROM  audit_table nt, #tmp1 a
    WHERE  i_date   =  @pIDate
    and nt.a_date = a.a_date
    and nt.f_id = a.f_id
union
select t_account,t_id, product
    FROM  n_audit_table t, #tmp2 a
    WHERE  t.item_date =  @pIDate
    and t.a_date = a.a_date
    and t.f_id = a.f_id
```

Both the tables having indexes on  i_date, a_date, f_id. Please find below showplan where it is long time.
    QUERY PLAN FOR STATEMENT 2 (at line 24).
Optimized using Serial Mode

```
STEP 1
    The type of query is INSERT.

10 operator(s) under root

   |ROOT:EMIT Operator (VA = 10)
   |
   |   |INSERT Operator (VA = 9)
   |   |  The update mode is direct.
   |   |
   |   |   |HASH UNION Operator (VA = 8)  has 2 children.
   |   |   | Using Worktable1 for internal storage.
   |   |   |  Key Count: 3
   |   |   |
   |   |   |   |NESTED LOOP JOIN Operator (VA = 3) (Join Type: Inner Join)
   |   |   |   |
   |   |   |   |   |SCAN Operator (VA = 0)
   |   |   |   |   |  FROM TABLE
   |   |   |   |   |  #tmp1
   |   |   |   |   |  a
   |   |   |   |   |  Table Scan.
   |   |   |   |   |  Forward Scan.
   |   |   |   |   |  Positioning at start of table.
   |   |   |   |   |  Using I/O Size 2 Kbytes for data pages.
   |   |   |   |   |  With LRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for data pages.
   |   |   |   |
   |   |   |   |   |RESTRICT Operator (VA = 2)(5)(0)(0)(0)(0)
   |   |   |   |   |
   |   |   |   |   |   |SCAN Operator (VA = 1)
   |   |   |   |   |   |  FROM TABLE
   |   |   |   |   |   |  audit_table
   |   |   |   |   |   |  nt
   |   |   |   |   |   |  Index : IX_audit_table
   |   |   |   |   |   |  Forward Scan.
   |   |   |   |   |   |  Positioning by key.
   |   |   |   |   |   |  Keys are:
   |   |   |   |   |   |    i_date ASC
   |   |   |   |   |   |    a_date ASC
   |   |   |   |   |   |  Using I/O Size 2 Kbytes for index leaf pages.
   |   |   |   |   |   |  With LRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for index leaf pages.
   |   |   |   |   |   |  Using I/O Size 2 Kbytes for data pages.
   |   |   |   |   |   |  With LRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for data pages.
   |   |   |
   |   |   |   |NESTED LOOP JOIN Operator (VA = 7) (Join Type: Inner Join)
   |   |   |   |
   |   |   |   |   |SCAN Operator (VA = 4)
   |   |   |   |   |  FROM TABLE
   |   |   |   |   |  #tmp2
   |   |   |   |   |  a
   |   |   |   |   |  Table Scan.
   |   |   |   |   |  Forward Scan.
   |   |   |   |   |  Positioning at start of table.
   |   |   |   |   |  Using I/O Size 2 Kbytes for data pages.
   |   |   |   |   |  With LRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for data pages.
   |   |   |   |
   |   |   |   |   |RESTRICT Operator (VA = 6)(5)(0)(0)(0)(0)
   |   |   |   |   |
   |   |   |   |   |   |SCAN Operator (VA = 5)
   |   |   |   |   |   |  FROM TABLE
   |   |   |   |   |   |  n_audit_table
   |   |   |   |   |   |  t
   |   |   |   |   |   |  Index : IX_n_audit_table
   |   |   |   |   |   |  Forward Scan.
   |   |   |   |   |   |  Positioning by key.
   |   |   |   |   |   |  Keys are:
   |   |   |   |   |   |    i_date ASC
   |   |   |   |   |   |    a_date ASC
   |   |   |   |   |   |  Using I/O Size 2 Kbytes for index leaf pages.
   |   |   |   |   |   |  With LRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for index leaf pages.
   |   |   |   |   |   |  Using I/O Size 2 Kbytes for data pages.
   |   |   |   |   |   |  With LRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for data pages.
   |   |
   |   |  TO TABLE
   |   |  #tmp
   |   |  Using I/O Size 2 Kbytes for data pages.


 Total estimated I/O cost for statement 2 (at line 24): 29322945.
```

Comment: Have you looked at the query plan?  Where is the most cost happening?

Comment: Most cost happening while doing union. i have updated my query with show plan. Please have a look and suggest

Comment: Can someone please help me on this query ?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt its a union issue. Queries are more probable troublemaker.

I suppose you should start from adding indexes on your temp tables:

```
create table #tmp1( f_id smallint, a_date smalldatetime ) 
Create clustered index IX1Temp on #tmp1(f_id ) 
Create clustered index IX2Temp on #tmp1(a_date ) 
...
```

Also, I see not much sense in #tmp1, #tmp2 the way you use them. You could call CTE instead. Also. I would recommend you to try PARTITION BY instead GROUP BY statement.

Answer (score 0):

According to the query execution plan, the problem is the table scans on the temporary tables.

Please get the execution plan for the following query:

```
insert into #tmp
select t_account,t_id, product
FROM
    audit_table nt,
    (
        select f_id, a_date = max(a_date)
        FROM  audit_table
        WHERE  i_date =  @pIDate
        group by f_id
    ) a
WHERE
    i_date   =  @pIDate
    and nt.a_date = a.a_date
    and nt.f_id = a.f_id
union
select t_account,t_id, product
FROM
    n_audit_table t,
    (
        select f_id , a_date = max( a_date )
        FROM  n_audit_table
        WHERE  i_date =  @pIDate
        group by f_id
    ) a
WHERE
    t.item_date =  @pIDate
    and t.a_date = a.a_date
    and t.f_id = a.f_id
```

Answer (score 0):

How many rows end up in each of the temporary tables? 
Looks like the temporary tables could be replaced by using [HAVING](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp), I would need to test it, it is always complicated when your group by is on a single column and you require more columns in the output.

Try running this statement with [SET STATISTICS PLANCOST ON](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00976.1502/html/statistics/statistics25.htm) and SET STATISTICS IO ON as that would give a good idea of the number of pages that are scanned and if Sybase is going wrong somewhere while optimising the query.